# Displaying different cursor while holding left mouse button using Chrome 32

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

The goal is to have the cursor change, if the left mouse button is held down over an element, in this example a button (same behavior was observed for a canvas element as well).
Strangely, in Chrome 32.0.1700.76 the cursor does not change as expected, if the mouse button is held down in the upper area of the button, up to about 60 pixels from the top.
Note that the problem only occurs, if the button is located at the very top of the webpage.
That's why i can't show the effect on JSFiddle.

This code sample can be used to reproduce the supposed bug:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            #testButton {
                cursor: pointer;
            }
            #testButton:active {
                cursor: move;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button id="testButton" style="width:200px;height:200px">click</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Firefox and IE switch the cursor as expected on holding the left mouse.
Can anyone confirm this misbehavior or propose a way to fix it for Chrome?

Comment: Chrome 34.0.1788.0 Dev displays it correctly.

Comment: Works for me in chrome 32.0.1700.102

Comment: Please link to a live sample, it's likely the reason you're getting the bug is another element overlapping it.

Comment: No, I still get the bug with Chrome 32.0.1700.107 m with exactly the code above pasted into a html file. But as i said the latest development release displays it correctly, so it's obviously a bug that will be fixed soon. @smitt04: I'm using Win7, maybe it works with Win8.

Comment: it could be a bug with the OS, I am using OSX, maybe it is only on windows

Answer (score 0):

Are you emulating touch events in Chrome?

Open the settings for the inspector and in the "Overrides" section turn off "Emulate touch events".

Comment: I didn't have it turned on.